# Changing Primary Key using Entity Framework Core Migrations

Tags: primary-key, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to Change the Primary key of a table via Entity Framework Core Migrations:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
        migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_Permissions",
            table: "Permissions");
}
```

When I try to update the database I get the following error message:

```
To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.
```

How can I update the database?

Comment: I don't think migrations supports this specialized scenario. You'll have to program it yourself.

Comment: what if you drop the column first? migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "Id",
                schema: "dbo",
                table: "Permissions");

  migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_Permissions",
            table: "Permissions");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution:
This seems to be a bug in EF Core 1.1

I changed the Migration file.

More Information about this can be found here: https://thisworksonmymachine.com/2017/02/13/ef-core-the-setup-part-4/

Comment: That only works if there are no references to the primary key yet.

Comment: @GertArnold Yep if the primary key is referenced you need to remove all foreign keys and add them again, it's a pain but it works

Comment: Link seems to be dead. Please can you update your answer to explain what you did. Thanks

Comment: Link is dead. Can you please update your answer.

Comment: The Wayback Machine has a copy http://web.archive.org/web/20170214123452/https://thisworksonmymachine.com/2017/02/13/ef-core-the-setup-part-4/

Answer (score 2):

It's always a risky idea to manipulate the migrations...
The simplest way is to clean the slate, if possible:
Take the table out from the DBContext (this will drop the table)
Create Migration and update database
Restore the table in the context and do your changes.
Create Migration and update database.

Obviously, you need to consider backup and restore of data and constraints...

Answer (score 2):

The following is not a solution for everyone. Namely, if you have an established database in multiple environments.

If you don't care about your migrations, simply start from scratch by deleting all of your migrations. Then recreate the first one with your new schema. Should work just fine.

Comment: This isn't always an option when you have an existing database in another environment.

Comment: Like I said "if you dont care about your past migrations"

Answer (score 2):

On attempting to get IdentityServer4 EF migrations (SQLServer) I had this same problem. Updating Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore to v2.1.3 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools to v2.1.3 seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: You're lucky. I've got this error on 2.2.4, latest version of 2.2 - and there's no updates (