# Entity Framework Core Migration fails in Case of Change to ValueGenerationStrategy

Tags: sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have annotated some of my model classes' keys with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`
and added a migration.

When running `Update-Database` I keep getting following error message:

> To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.

I also tried to `Update-Database` with a complete new database, to no avail as the error is the same.

When changing the identity property in SQL Server Management Studio, I do not get such error but I would like to avoid a mix of code and DB first approach.

Is there a way to either

1. force the update to drop and recreate the **column**
2. or drop and recreate the **table** ?

EDIT1:
To answer a question from the comments. My model class before looked like:

```
 public partial class MyModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(70)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
...
}
```

This is my model class after adding the annotation:

```
 public partial class MyModel
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [MaxLength(70)]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Can you share code (before & after) of at least one class?

Comment: @Smit I have added the class to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Primary Key using Entity Framework Core Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798708/changing-primary-key-using-entity-framework-core-migrations)

Comment: This is not a duplicate post.